# SQL to get result from one query as columns to another query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes
(
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name    TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE events
(
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    node    INTEGER REFERENCES nodes,
    etime   TIMESTAMP,
    value   TEXT
);
```

Is there a query to get the values from the `nodes` table as columns to the `events` table?

For a simple example I would like something like this:

```
 node1 |  node2 |  node3
-------+--------+--------
event1 |        |
       | event2 |
       |        | event3
```

Is this possible?

What I **really** would like, would be an SQL query that could output something like this:

```
       etime        |  node1  |  node2  |  node3
--------------------+---------+---------+--------
2011-04-26 13:12:23 | Event 1 |         | Event 2
2011-04-26 15:52:43 |         | Event 3 |        
2011-04-26 21:35:12 | Event 4 | Event 5 | Event 6
```

Where `node1` to `node3` comes from the `node` table, and the timestamps and `Event` texts comes from the `events` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called crosstab or pivot query, and there is no SQL-compliant way to generate one.

Quick googling says there's a [contrib module for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/14-CrossTab-Queries-in-PostgreSQL-using-tablefunc-contrib.html) (looks like [in core now](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)).

Another pretty interesting [blog post here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/) (first in google) - though it's not fully crosstab, as it has fixed number of columns.

Comment: The crosstab family of functions look promising. I'll have to experiment a little with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use grouping and aggregating on CASE expressions:

```
SELECT
  e.etime,
  MIN(CASE n.name WHEN 'node1' THEN e.value END) AS node1,
  MIN(CASE n.name WHEN 'node2' THEN e.value END) AS node2,
  MIN(CASE n.name WHEN 'node3' THEN e.value END) AS node3
FROM events e
  INNER JOIN nodes n ON e.node = n.id
GROUP BY
```